# Разделение предложения по словам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Разделение предложения по словам
пытаюсь через split, но не выходит.

> пример: a = "поeзд ушел в небо как табор цыган"
>
> нужно чтобы выводило  [поезд, ушел, в, небо, как, табор, цыган]

```
a = "one two three four"
a.split()
print(a)
```

`split` ничего не изменяет.

Comment: Что значит "не выходит"?

Comment: @SevenKing приведите пример кода

Comment: @LexHobbit
`a = "one two three four" 
a.split() 
print(a)`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ничего не изменяет split.

Comment: @SevenKing, split() и не должен исходную строку заменять на список, он просто возвращает список.

Answer (score 6):

`split()` не заменяет исходную строку на список (и не должен). Исходная строка остается неизменной, а просто возвращается список частей исходной строки. Как нужно делать:

```
a = "one two three four"
b = a.split()
print(b)  # ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: Спасибо, что то я туплю.

Answer (score 1):

Все типы данных делятся на 2 категории:

- `mutable` изменяемые : `dict, set` - после создания, объект можно измененить, и это останется тот же самый объект.
- `unmutable` неизменяемые : `int, float, complex, str, tuple, frozenset` - после создания, объект уже нельзя измененить, только пересоздать.

Вызывая у объекта метод, например `a.split()`, можно изменить лишь [`mutable`](http://old.pynsk.ru/posts/2015/Aug/17/sintaksis-python-izmeniaemye-i-neizmeniaemye-tipy-dannykh/#.WXdhe4iGOUl) объект.

Comment: То есть нельзя объявить переменную (int a = 0) и потом изменить её значение (a = a+3)? Просто питон не знаю, но стало интересно

Comment: [Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names)

Comment: Именно то, что нужно, спасибо!